# What happens to my Xamarin app after my subscription expires?

Tags: xamarin

Currently I am working on a Xamarin project which is basically a college news app (just like newspaper apps like "Times Of India" etc). I have used Microsoft Azure for updating news blogs.

My question is when my Xamarin subscription expires, will my app continue to work or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app itself will continue to work but you will not be able to recompile if you dont reactivate the Business licence

Comment: means I will be able to  send news updates to all users without any restriction ?

Comment: What do you mean with "news updates" ? I assume you mean some kind of new content for the users . If the app is able to fetch the new content from the internet then YES it will still work. If you need to recompile the app to provide the new content then NO it will not work

Answer (score 3):

Actually, if you buy any of the annual licenses, you are free to continue to recompile and develop. It is only the monthly indie licenses that prevent development if you do not renew. In either case your built app will not be affected